# Python scipy.spatial.Delaunay and copy.deepcopy malfunctioning with incremental parameter

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I have had a big problem using scipy.spatial.Delaunay function.

I initialize a variable named *tri* as it follows:

```
tri = Delaunay(ApsArray, incremental=True)
```

This code works perfectly, but since I have to use this triangulation in a for loop, I want to copy *tri* in another variable named *triTemp* (as a temporal variable).

I searched in python documentation and I found in the **copy** module, **deepcopy**, which permits me to copy *tri* in another site in memory pointed by triTemp:

```
triTemp = deepcopy(tri)
```

It works!, but when I try to add a new point to *triTemp*, this error appears:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-77-2f5ca634bc26>", line 1, in <module>
    tri.add_points([[0.2,0.3]])
  File "qhull.pyx", line 1544, in scipy.spatial.qhull._QhullUser.add_points (scipy\spatial\qhull.c:13938)
  File "qhull.pyx", line 446, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.add_points (scipy\spatial\qhull.c:4954)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have thought that the problem is with the parameter **incremental** because *triTemp*, is simply a copy in memory of *tri*, but my problem is that I don't know how to change this parameter without initializing *triTemp* again.

I want to use a copy, and not to calculate the triangulation again, because I think that it is more efficient, so if someone knows a method to reach this objective, please tell me.

Thanks to all, and sorry for the bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently (Scipy 0.15.1) not possible to copy Delaunay structures when in the incremental mode, because the incremental state of the triangulation is stored internally in Qhull.

If you only need some of the attributes e.g. `simplices` etc. you could only copy them.